# Property doesn't exist on type 'object' in React Native with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm very new to React Native and TypeScript so forgive me if the the question is trivial.

In my application I have a screen to which I'm navigating with `React-Navigation` I'm also passing a callback function through the navigation.

`navigation.navigate('BluredSuccess', {blurredSuccessCallback})`

I show the BlurredScreen for 2 secs and then I close using `navigation.pop` and call the callback function like this:

```
import { NavigationScreenProp } from 'react-navigation';
import { Route } from '@react-navigation/native';

interface Props {
    navigation?: NavigationScreenProp,
    route: Route<any>
}

const LoginOtpSuccess : React.FC<Props> = ({navigation, route: {params}}) => {

    React.useEffect(() => { setTimeout(() => {
                
        navigation.pop()
        params.blurredSuccessCallback() // here I see an error.

    }, 2000) })

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <BlurView
                style={styles.absolute}
                blurType="light"
                blurAmount={40}
                reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
            />
            <Image source={require('../../../assets/otp_success.png')} style={{width:90, height:90}}></Image>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Now the code works in general but I keep seeing an error on my callback method stating:

```
Property 'blurredSuccessCallback' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

I also see `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` on the params variable.

How can I fix this error? What should be the correct types of `navigation` and `route` in my `Props` interface I don't think using any is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly annotate your properties, `route` and `navigation`. In general, any type that contains optional fields by using the `?`-indicator could potentially be undefined and you need to take that into consideration wherever you use these fields.

One common way to type your props here:

```
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NavigationScreenProp } from 'react-navigation';

// Your stack here, or import this to fit your needs
type RootParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  BlurredSuccess: { blurredSuccessCallback: () => void };
};

type BlurredSuccessRouteProp = RouteProp<RootParamList, 'BlurredSuccess'>;
type BlurredSuccessNavigationProp = NavigationScreenProp<RootParamList, 'BlurredSuccess'>;

type Props = {
  navigation: BlurredSuccessNavigationProp,
  route: BlurredSuccessRouteProp;
};

const LoginOtpSuccess = ({ route, navigation }: Props) => {
    const { blurredSuccessCallback } = route.params;
    React.useEffect(() => { setTimeout(() => {
        navigation.pop();
        blurredSuccessCallback();
    }, 2000) })

    return (
        // ...
    )
}
```

See [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```js
interface Props {
    navigation?: NavigationScreenProp
    route?: {
      params?: {
        blurredSuccessCallback?(): void
      }
     }
}
```